# Can I get a visa when crossing by land from Raxaul, India to Birgunj, Nepal?

Tags: visas, nepal

Is it possible to get a visa-on-arrival from Nepal when crossing (by land) from Raxaul, India into Birgunj, Nepal?

I don't have an appointment. I'm traveling by bicycle, so I'm not sure exactly when I'll arrive. Ideally I'd like to just show up, leave India, enter Nepal, stand in a queue, pay some money, and get a visa.

Is it possible to show up without an appointment and get a visa for Nepal when entering Birgunj from Raxaul?

Comment: No one can answer this question without your nationality... Please edit to include all relevant information

Comment: For the answer to be useful to the general reader, it should include answers for *all* nationalities.

Comment: @HoboHacker What research did you do before posting your question https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask? A simple internet search throws up an answer https://travelnepal.com/travel-advice/nepal-visa-arrival/

Comment: @HoboHacker In several cases the answers to visa related questions for Country B depend heavily on not only the nationality A of the person wanting a visa, but also what other visas that person might already hold for unrelated Country C.  As such, the question and answers can very much be useful *only* to that specific person and the visas they already hold, and would be impossible to answer in a generic manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any [*on-arrival visa*](https://tia.immigration.gov.np/page/on-arrival-tourist-visa)-eligible (this is different from the [*visa on arrival*](https://www.immigration.gov.np/page/visa-on-arrival) facility operated at Tribhuvan International Airport (TIA) airport) nationality can get an on-arrival tourist visa at any Entry/Exit Point's [Immigration Offices](https://www.immigration.gov.np/offices)

Those are the only nationalities not eligible for a OaV/VoA

- Nigeria
- Ghana
- Zimbabwe
- Swaziland
- Cameroon
- Somalia
- Liberia
- Ethiopia
- Iraq
- Palestine
- Afghanistan
- Syria
- Refugees with travel document

> Visas obtained on Arrival at the Entry and Exit points are 'Tourist Visas'

---

You can pre-fill the form for the visa online and pay **in USD** at the border :

- 15 Days – USD 30
- 30 Days – USD 50
- 90 Days – USD 125

Or you can also pay online pre-arrival, both at [Nepaliport](https://nepaliport.immigration.gov.np/)

---

Indian nationals only need their passport or Elector card to enter Nepal